# Oracle SQL Developer - DB Session Timeout

Tags: security, session, oracle-sqldeveloper, dbconnection

I'm running Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.3.16.  When my DB connection session times out, the previous result set from a query I ran is still displayed under "Query Results."  For security reasons at my organizations, is there anyway (an option/feature in SQL Developer) to make the result set invisible or "go away" and have it not displayed as soon as my DB connection session times out?

Comment: No. When the session times out, it has no way of reading your mind to know that you really don't want the data any more. Is there some reason you can't just pay attention and not let your session time out without your getting rid of the data yourself?

Comment: Respectfully, not always.  My work environment is as such, that even if able to "do the right thing" and get rid of the data before my session time out, I still need to prove the ability to have the data "go away."  My organization understands that it's not always possible to clear your data before your session ends.  Especially in a place where there are 500 people, and there is constant foot traffic in and out of the office space.  But I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: If your organization understands, then it shouldn't be an issue when it happens. At the very least, can't you lock your workstation (screen) when you leave your desk? Problem solved.

Comment: That's where I have to respectfully disagree.  Just because you know  something bad happens, doesn't mean you cannot take action to prevent it in the future.  I do lock my WS every time I leave my desk, but it doesn't help when someone's in my office space.  I get your point, I really do, but what you and I may consider common sense, doesn't count come Audit time.